# Laravel create table using migration error

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-migrations

I want to create a `tbl_teacher_students` table using migration..

My command is `php artisan make:migration create_tbl_teacher_students_table`.

I also tried adding `--create=tbl_teacher_students` but both gives me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateFailedJobsTable, because the name is already in use

 Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

 Cannot declare class CreateFailedJobsTable, because the name is already in use
```

I can't find anything about `CreateFailedJobsTable` error relating to migration.
Additional, I also tried adding column to an existing table but it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening, because on your **database/migrataions/** directory `create_failed_jobs_table.....` created twice. Delete one. Then run `composer dump-autoload` and try again. This will solve the problem